# Record type showing NULL in trigger

Tags: trigger, record-type

I have to trigger some actions for records of a certain record type. When doing this via trigger and getting the record type value of the record in the debug statement I am receiving NULL, which is why it is not going inside my IF Statement. What is the mistake I am making ??

`Trigger.newMap.get(FARecId).Recordtype.DeveloperName` is coming as NULL

Thanks!

**Trigger**

```
Trigger FATrigger on Financial_Account__c (After Update) 
{
    if(trigger.isAfter && trigger.isUpdate)
    {
        For(Id FARecId : Trigger.newMap.keySet())
        {
            System.debug('----Record type name is' + Trigger.newMap.get(FARecId).Recordtype.DeveloperName);

            IF(Trigger.newMap.get(FARecId).Recordtype.DeveloperName == 'Retail')
            {
                System.debug('----Inside IF Statement 1----');
                FATriggerController.PerPaidLesThn60(Trigger.New);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Only the object's base fields are loaded from the database in triggers. To get related objects, you need to either query for them or use describe calls. In this specific case, you would use a describe call:

```
Map<Id, RecordTypeInfo> rtinfos = Financial_Account__c.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosById();
for(Financial_Account__c record: Trigger.new) {
    String rtName = '-- Master --';
    if(rtinfos.containsKey(record.RecordTypeId)) {
        rtName = rtinfos.get(record.RecordTypeId).getName();
    }
    System.debug(rtName);
}
```

Comment: I had to add "sObjectType" => "Financial_Account__c.sObjectType.getDescribe()..."

Answer (score 1):

The answer by sfdcfox solves the problem.

I have other approach which involves creating a formula field on your Financial Account record which fetches record type name.

You can access that field in your trigger, it makes code simpler but you sacrifice a formula field.